# FFMpeg - Save JPGs From Stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a multicast UDP video stream. I am trying to write an FFMPEG script that will capture that to JPGs, ideally at the framerate the video is broadcast at (25fps).

Would someone be able to help let me know the kind of command I need to do this. (I can find commands to update a single JPG, but I would like a continuous stream of JPGs to be saved).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i stream -vsync 0 -q:v 2 frames%d.jpg
```

`-vsync 0` will ensure no received frames are dropped or duplicated. `-q:v 2` sets video quality. `2` may be overkill. Experiment.

Comment: Hi thanks. This just gives me 1 frame called framesd.jpg though and then crashes. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Share the full log.